# Best way to initiate RSACryptoServiceProvider from x509Certificate2?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, certificate, rsacryptoserviceprovider

What is the best way to initate a new `RSACryptoServiceProvider` object from an `X509Certificate2` I pulled out of a key store? The certificate is associated with both public (for encryption) and private (for decryption) keys.

I'm current using the `FromXmlString` method but there must be a better way.

Thanks

Comment: Please consider changing the accepted answer to Rosdi Kasim's.  The currently accepted answer is now very out of date and unreliable.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

*Note: While this is the accepted answer and was valid back in 2011, this code won't work now under .NET Core. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49777672/245183) if you are using .NET Framework 4.6+, or .NET Core / .NET.*

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider publicKeyProvider = 
    (RSACryptoServiceProvider)certificate.PublicKey.Key;
```

and

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider privateKeyProvider = 
    (RSACryptoServiceProvider)certificate.PrivateKey;
```

The key property on the public or private key property of the certificate is of type AsymmetricAlgorithm.

Comment: Thanks blowdart, worked like a charm. Maybe I should buy your book.

Comment: Note: should be `certificate.PrivateKey;` not `certificate.PrivateKey.Key;`

Comment: Great answer, short and sweet. Are the non-RSA providers just irrelevant? Presumably there's a reason why these properties are AsymmetricAlgorithm, and no guarantee their runtime type will actually be RSACryptoServiceProvider..?

Comment: Well Elliptic Curve is also asymmetric, but there's no real concept of keys. And of course a base class makes for expandability should someone come out with something greater.

Comment: I'll buy his book if he covers RSA keys, import exports.  I gave up reading and writing ASN.1 public keys formatted as SubjectPublicKeyInfo.  Went to Bouncy Castle and am 99% of the way there.  (PS you working on AntiXSS on codeplex?  When is the next version?)

Comment: Know what's funny?  Exposing the PrivateKey in public environment is a bad security practice, especially on the Cloud servers.  :-/

Comment: doesnt work 'System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng' to type 'System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider'.''

Comment: I'm getting error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng' to type 'System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider'." in .NET Core 3.1

Answer (score 46):

**The recommended way** is to use `RSA` base class and call `certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey()`.

```
RSA publicKeyProvider = certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey();
```

Since .NET 4.6, casting to `RSACryptoServiceProvider` as suggested by @blowdart is no longer recommended. This is even more an issue now since there are several versions of .NET (such as .NET Core).

By casting to `RSACryptoServiceProvider` that way, there is a good chance you might get this cast exception (depending on the platform and libraries used):

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng' to type 'System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider'

The reason is the actual implementation could be different from each platform, on Windows `RSACng` is used.

[Here is a link that describes this issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cc336754-4b17-418d-86f2-e67a80271843/using-x509certificate2-to-get-privatekey-causes-cryptographicexception-invalid-provider-type?forum=csharpgeneral) (look for answer by Jeremy Barton).

Comment: I was able to move forward with this approach.

Answer (score 9):

Blowdart's answer is indeed correct. However, for clarity I should point out that if you want your RSACryptoServiceProvider instance to contain **both** the public and private keys of the X509 certificate (assuming the certificate does have a private key). Check the certificate's HasPrivateKey property.

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa;
if (cert.HasPrivateKey)
    rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;
else
    rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PublicKey.Key;
```

In the case of RSA when only the public key is present the RSA Parameters will be only Exponent and Modulus, all others will be null; If on the other hand the private key is present the RSA Parameters will contain D, DP, DQ, Exponent, InverseQ, Modulus, P and Q.

Comment: (RSACryptoServiceProvider)(c.HasPrivateKey ? c.PrivateKey : c.PublicKey.Key); However: I wouldn't ever do this. I'd only load the private key when I intended to use the provider for something that *requires* it - and then of course it's no help just loading the public key instead.

Comment: Dag is correct, but to clarify... I either want to decrypt with the private key, or encrypt with the public key.  There's no situation where I want just whatever might be available.